# How to embed some application window in my application using any Python GUI framework

Tags: python, user-interface

I want some application to look like widget inside my Python application.

That's all. I dont need any interaction between them. I'm interested in solutions in **any** GUI toolkit for both windows and x windows.

It would be nice to have a solution with Tkinter but it's not crucial.

Comment: I think it's highly platform dependent. Please give more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using GTK on X windows (i.e. Linux, FreeBSD, Solaris), you can use the XEMBED protocol to embed widgets using [`gtk.Socket`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtksocket.html).  Unfortunately, the application that you're launching has to explicitly support it so that you can tell it to embed itself.  Some applications don't support this.  Notably, I can't find a way to do it with Firefox.

Nonetheless, here's a sample program that will run either an X terminal or an Emacs session inside a GTK window:

```
import os
import gtk
from gtk import Socket, Button, Window, VBox, HBox

w = Window()
e = Button("Emacs")
x = Button("XTerm")
s = Socket()
v = VBox()
h = HBox()
w.add(v)
v.add(s)
h.add(e)
h.add(x)
v.pack_start(h, expand=False)

def runemacs(btn):
    x.set_sensitive(False); e.set_sensitive(False)
    os.spawnlp(os.P_NOWAIT, "emacs", 
        "emacs", "--parent-id", str(s.get_id()))

def runxterm(btn):
    x.set_sensitive(False); e.set_sensitive(False)
    os.spawnlp(os.P_NOWAIT, "xterm",
        "xterm", "-into", str(s.get_id()))

e.connect('clicked', runemacs)
x.connect('clicked', runxterm)
w.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: Do you happen to know why embeded xterm doesn't receive keyboard events?

Comment: @MeanEYE, may be a matter of focus?

Comment: @Hibou57 oh, I solved this problem long time ago. :) Thanks for the effort. What I did was `object.child_focus(gtk.DIR_TAB_FORWARD)`, `object` being the socket.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough reputation to comment on Glyphs answer. To make xterm work, in addition to the comments above one needs to also add

```
XTerm*allowSendEvents: True
```

to `~/.Xresources`. (and perhaps reload those, with `xrdb -load ~/.Xresources`)